# How could the Hogwarts elves be freed by Hermione when Dumbledore was their master?

Tags: j-k-rowling, harry-potter

In Harry Potter, Hermione creates the S.P.E.W. (Society for the Promotion of Elfish Welfare) organization, and starts hiding hats for the elves to find and be freed. The elves were offended and left all the work in that area to Dobby. But how could they be freed by a student, when Dumbledore was their master?

Comment: Related posts on another site: [Could Hermione really free the Hogwarts house-elves with her knitted hats?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26700/31394), [Why are Hermione's efforts to free the House-elves so incompetent?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79805/31394), [Who owns the Hogwarts house-elves?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26698/31394) You'll notice that the answers are a mixed bag, suggesting that there's no clear single answer and multiple interpretations to this one.